# Prevent event bubbling when using the checked binding in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I'm building a UI using KnockoutJs and Twitter Bootstrap.

I'm using the `checked` binding inside a Bootstrap dialogue called `dropdown-toggle`.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        Facets
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <!-- ko foreach: facets -->
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Visible" /> 
            <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
        </li>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Everything is fine except that I would like the drop down dialogue to remain opened when checking the checkboxes.

Here is a fiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeEast/L3KfG/2/

I have tried creating my own binding handler which uses the checked binding explicitly together with `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` which leaves the dialogue  opened, but prevents the checkbox to be checked.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It sounds like you were on the right track.  You basically want to do the equivalent of:

```
click: function() { return true; }, clickBubble: false
```

**OR** This could be done in a custom binding like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stopBubble = {
  init: function(element) {
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "click", function(event) {
         event.cancelBubble = true;
         if (event.stopPropagation) {
            event.stopPropagation(); 
         }
    });
  }
};
```

The normal click/event handler attached by KO will prevent the default action unless you return true. However, if we hook up our own event handler, then we only need to prevent it from bubbling.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeEast/PyNfg/1/

Comment: Nice! Clever to catch the bubbling in the parent element! Thanks! Btw: I edited: `event.cancelBubble;` -> `event.cancelBubble = true;`

Comment: how can I upvote an answer more than one time, you saved my life.

Comment: I don't know why `clickBubble: false` does not work, but custom solution `stopBubble: true` works perfect, but in my case not on parent but child node