# Combining checked binding with click binding on containing element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In my view model I have a boolean property that's visualized by a checkbox in the view. I want the user to be able to click on the containing element as well to toggle the property, but that poses problems when the user clicks the checkbox: the change is not registered then.

Consider this view:

```html
<div class="my-option" data-bind="click: toggleOption1">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isOption1Checked" />
    Entire div is clickable to select this option.
</div>
```

With this view model:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.isOption1Checked = ko.observable(false);
    self.toggleOption1 = function(){
        self.isOption1Checked(!self.isOption1Checked());
    };
};
```

As you can see in [this corresponding jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLxs4eq3/), this will **not** allow you to click on the checkbox to change the boolean observable. This kinda makes sense to me, probably the click handler changes the value, but the checked binding also handles the change and reverts it.

The general solution I felt I needed was a **one way checked binding** or something of the sort, so I tried using the `attr` binding:

```html
<div class="my-option" data-bind="click: toggleOption1">
    <input type="checkbox" 
           data-bind="attr: { checked: isOption1Checked() ? 'checked' : '???'" />
    Entire div is clickable to select this option.
</div>
```

However, this will not work: there is no `checked="false"` option in html. You just omit the `checked` attribute altogether. I don't think the `attr` binding can do that however.

One other workaround I thought of was to create my own binding (possibly based on / delegating the read bit to the default `checked` binding), but it feels like overkill. Am I missing an obvious, elegant Knockout solution?

My current workaround (trying to evade creating such a custom binding) involves some elaborate view logic:

```html
<div class="my-option" data-bind="click: toggleOption1">
    <!-- ko if: isOption1Checked -->
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: !isOption1Checked() -->
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <!-- /ko -->
    Entire div is clickable to select this option.
</div>
```

[This works](http://jsfiddle.net/yLxs4eq3/1/), but is very verbose to my taste.

Any other elegant, concise way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, just after posting and searching some more I found the answer in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14321012/419956). Here's the specifics for the scenario from my question:

```html
<div class="my-option" data-bind="click: toggleOption1">
    <input type="checkbox" 
           data-bind="checked: isOption1Checked, 
                      click: function() { return true; }, 
                      clickBubble: false" />
    Entire div is clickable to select this option.
</div>
```

I'll leave this answer and question here as a duplicate, should it help a random Googling internet user that words his question similar to mine as opposed to similar to the other one.