# Clicking on an input[checkbox]'s label will fire twice the parent's click event (knockout)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Consider [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9rkrahm6/) I have an `<input type='checkbox'>` linked to its corresponding `<label>`. On their parent, I have a `click` binding.

The problem is, clicking on the `<label>` will trigger the parent's click twice, whereas clicking on the `<input>` will trigger it only once.

Considering I want to keep the current HTML structure (`<label>` next to the `<input>`), is there a way to make the `<label>` behave like the `<input>` element? (aka trigger the `click` only once)

**EDIT**: If i remove the `return true;` statement from the `click` handler's function, it wont trigger twice, but also, it won't select the checkbox. Selecting the checkbox is required. [Here is a case](http://jsfiddle.net/yxsuym8e/1/) where I don't have the action on the parent element. If you click on the `<label>`, it will check the `<input>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer for you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321012/prevent-event-bubbling-when-using-the-checked-binding-in-knockoutjs). The trick is to make the label stop bubbling with a custom binding.

```
<label for="test" data-bind="stopBubble:parentAction">TestLabel</label>
```

The `stopBubble` binding is at the link, and also in the Fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/9rkrahm6/2/

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand why this is, but removing the for attribute from your label will prevent this from happening.

The label still sits where it did previously.

EDIT
Try this if the div needs to set the box too:
HTML:

```
<div class="parent" data-bind="click: checkTheBox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="test" data-bind="checked: checkedFlag">
  <label for="test">TestLabel</label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function testVM(){
var self = this;

self.checkedFlag = ko.observable(false);

self.checkTheBox = function(){
    console.log("In funct")
    console.log("before: " + self.checkedFlag())
    if (self.checkedFlag()){
        self.checkedFlag(false);
    }
    else{
        self.checkedFlag(true);
    }
    console.log("after: " + self.checkedFlag())
};

self.myTest = function(data, event){

};
```

}

ko.applyBindings(new testVM());

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've edited my question to include some important info i initially forgot. :) basically, if i remove that attribute (which is the 'link' between the label and the input), the input won't get checked.

Comment: The box needs to be checked when clicking the div also?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
    event.preventDefault(); // stop bubbling
```

or simply

```
    return false; // is equals to: event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();
```

in the `parentAction` function.

#### Update

It looks like click event fires down from the `checked` knockout binding.
The following code will fix it, but it smells like a hack. May be somebody will propose the better treatment.

```
function testVM(){
    var self = this;

    self.checkedFlag = ko.observable(false);

    self.checkedFlag.subscribe(function() {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    self.parentAction = function(data, event){
        alert('triggered');
        //event.stopPropagation();
        //event.preventDefault();
        return true;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. See the edit to the question :)