# Layering Knockout Click binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Very simple scenario here, I'm hoping there is a simple solution.... Jquery would handle this but for efficiency I want to use the knockout click binding.

```
<ul>
    <li data-bind="click: ShowMyUser">
        <span>My Email Address Or Username</span>
        <i data-bind="click: DeleteMyUser">Delete Icon</i>
    </li>
<ul>
```

In this example I have a list of Usernames or Email Addresses. What I would like to do, is on the click event of the ROW (e.g. li), show the user details. On the click event of the DELETE icon I would like to show a pop up.

I have both of those methods written and working. **My problem** is that on clicking the delete icon it ALSO fires the `li` event.

In order to get round this I have implemented the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span data-bind="click: ShowMyUser">My Email Address Or Username</span>
        <i data-bind="click: DeleteMyUser">Delete Icon</i>
    </li>
<ul>
```

However this means that the user must click on the text, I'm not a big fan of this, I think it's un-intuitive.

Any thoughts guys n gals?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321012/prevent-event-bubbling-when-using-the-checked-binding-in-knockoutjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KnockoutJS already supports stop bubbling, no need to write it from scratch: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html (go to Note 4)

Just add `clickBubble: false` to the child click.

```
<ul>
  <li data-bind="click: ShowMyUser">
    <span>My Email Address Or Username</span>
    <i data-bind="click: DeleteMyUser, clickBubble: false">Delete Icon</i>
  </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to [Roy J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/392102/roy-j) for posting a very helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321012/prevent-event-bubbling-when-using-the-checked-binding-in-knockoutjs), from that page I found a solution. Firstly I created the following bindingHandler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stopBubble = {
  init: function(element) {
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "click", function(event) {
         event.cancelBubble = true;
         if (event.stopPropagation) {
            event.stopPropagation(); 
         }
    });
  }
};
```

I then added this to my delete icon so it would not propagate through and call the li click event:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span data-bind="click: ShowMyUser">My Email Address Or Username</span>
        <i data-bind="click: DeleteMyUser, stopBubble: true">Delete Icon</i>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use binding `clickBubble` <s>or return false from `DeleteMyUser` click handler</s>

if you want to have dynamic logic to the bubble but seperated from the click handler you can do

https://jsfiddle.net/h1mrfLe6/